# How can i deepclone an object which has a react.element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deep-copy

Deep cloning an object which has a react element will break that element and you can no longer render that element,
[Here is an example showing this issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-element-demo-dqr09?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import Demo from "./Demo";

export default function App() {
  const test = <div>I'm a react element</div>;
  console.log("test", test);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Demo obj={{ element: test }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

//Demo.js

```
import React from "react";
// import cloneDeep from "lodash.clonedeep";
import CloneDeep from "clone-deep";

const Demo = ({ obj }) => {
  const newProps = CloneDeep(obj);
  console.log(newProps.element);
  // console.log("Demo element", newProps.element);
  return (
    <div>
      I'm Demo Component
      {newProps.element}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

I also tried a couple of other deep cloning libraries but none of them seems to work in my case!, so do you know an library which does this ? or maybe i can fix the current cloning library by doing something ? or maybe i can write my own deep cloning, any tip on that?
What i have tried so far:
1- Using `import CloneDeep from "clone-deep";` which will causes an `objects are not valid as a react child` error
2-Using `import cloneDeep from "lodash.clonedeep";` which doesn't have the same error as the previous library but throws an `infinity loop, Max Stack` error!
Thanks.

Comment: if you are just trying to clone the parent props element (ie obj),i think no need to use deepclone package ,react has inbuilt function for cloning an element ,you can use 

const newProps = React.cloneElement(obj) in your demo.js

Comment: @warmachine, This is just a test case of my actual need, in my program the object i have is a deep nested object and sometimes it can contain `React.element`s and thats when the problem occurs, actually i hadn't notice why this was caused until i built the said test case, but i suppose i could use `React.cloneElement` if i decide to build my own deep cloning.

Comment: my suggestion is if you are cloning an element ,go for React.cloneElement,apart from that what i understand that package(ie clone-deep) is not meant for elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to `github` `clone-deep` copied their code and made a couple of changes
1-First i check if the value is an react element using `React.isValidElement`
2-Thanks to @warmachine i use`React.cloneElement` if the object is a react element  to clone the object and if it is not, i do what the library always did

Here you can see the complete code:

```
import React from "react";
const clone = require("shallow-clone");
const typeOf = require("kind-of");
const isPlainObject = require("is-plain-object");

export function cloneDeep(val, instanceClone) {
  if (React.isValidElement(val)) {
    return React.cloneElement(val);
  } else {
    const valueType = typeOf(val);
    switch (valueType) {
      case "object":
        return cloneObjectDeep(val, instanceClone);
      case "array":
        return cloneArrayDeep(val, instanceClone);
      default: {
        return clone(val);
      }
    }
  }
}

function cloneObjectDeep(val, instanceClone) {
  if (typeof instanceClone === "function") {
    return instanceClone(val);
  }
  if (instanceClone || isPlainObject(val)) {
    const res = new val.constructor();
    for (let key in val) {
      res[key] = cloneDeep(val[key], instanceClone);
    }
    return res;
  }
  return val;
}

function cloneArrayDeep(val, instanceClone) {
  const res = new val.constructor(val.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    res[i] = cloneDeep(val[i], instanceClone);
  }
  return res;
}
```

This is of course a temporarily solution until i find a better one or hopefully the git hub owner reflects on the issue i posted